# Tried to register two views with the same name

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-chartjs

[image]

I am not sure why it's returning this error. It might have to do something with one of the dependencies being incompatible with another. I also have installed a react-native-webview dependency along with canvas. I wonder if that's causing the error. My package.json is the following-

```
    {
  "name": "angularapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.37",
    "react-native-chartjs": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-dates": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.2",
    "react-native-scripts": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.63.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a line chart compatible with calendar in this code. Following is the main piece of code from App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Dates from 'react-native-dates';
import moment from 'moment';
import Chart from 'react-native-chartjs';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.chart = null;
    this.state = {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
      focusedInput: null,
      dates: []
    };
    this.handleDatesChange = this.handleDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFocusChange = this.handleFocusChange.bind(this);
    this.updateChart = this.updateChart.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.node, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "# of Likes",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }

  handleDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {
    let dates = [];
    for (
      let m = moment(startDate);
      m.diff(moment(endDate), "days") <= 0;
      m.add(1, "days")
    ) {
      dates.push(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    }
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate, dates }, () => {
      let data = this.randomData(this.state.dates.length);
      this.updateChart(this.state.dates, data);
    });
  }

  handleFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
  }

  updateChart(labels, data) {
    this.chart.data.labels = labels;
    this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
    this.chart.update();
  }

  randomData(length) {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
    return data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Dates
          startDateId="startDate"
          endDateId="endDate"
          startDate={this.state.startDate}
          endDate={this.state.endDate}
          onDatesChange={this.handleDatesChange}
          focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
          onFocusChange={this.handleFocusChange}
        />
        <Canvas ref={node => (this.node = node)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, replace

```
"react-native-webview": "^2.0.0"
```

with

```
"react-native-webview": "^10.3.2",
```

and do yarn or npm install.